# How can i fill video.Snippet.Tags with an array?

Tags: c#, youtube, upload, tags

I am using google youtube api v3 for uploading video to youtube with c#.
I want to fill tags with words from a description. 
Firstly; i am creating a list.

```
List<string> keywords=new List<string>();
```

after it, i am splitting the words.

```
string[] words = description.Split(' ');
```

if words>25, i will add 25 words to keywords, else i will add all.

```
int it;
if (words.Length > 25)
 {
   it= 25;
 }
 else
 {
   it = words.Length;
 }
//keywords.RemoveAll(); //i want to remove all list if i added before, but it is not working...
```

i am adding here.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <it; i++)
   {
     keywords.Add(words[i]);
   }
```

and i need to add keywords to youtube video tags. But it is getting only 1 word. I dont know why.

```
video.Snippet.Tags=keywords;
```

Comment: Firstly, what is in `description` and also `words`? Secondly, there's no need for the `if` and `for` loop, you can simply do `keywords = words.Take(25).ToList();` Also, as the `Tags` property takes an enumerable, you can simplify it even more to `video.Snippet.Tags = words.Take(25);`

Comment: i solved. Thanks. it was about commas. i replaced commas in words to " " and it solved.